# ¿Como extraer cierta parte de una cadena en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo las siguientes cadenas necesito extraer solamente los países

```
Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Peru.Llamadas
Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Reino Unido.Llamada
Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Espana.Llamada
Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Guadeloupe.Llamada
```

**N** veces países se pueden repetir los mismos paises

He intentado probar con el siguiente codigo:

```
$nombre = "Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Peru.Llamadas";      
$arrayNombre = explode(" ", $nombre, 7);      

print_r($arrayNombre[6]);
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

**a Peru.Llamadas**

Me hace falta sacar el pais de esa cadena

Comment: Hola Juan, te recomiendo echar un vistazo al siguiente artículo: [PHP: explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) la función en cuestión es la siguiente `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )` Generas un array y luego recuperas la posición donde se encuentre el país. Tal vez tengas un problema ya que se divide por `.` en vez de por espacio.

Comment: Intentaste algo? esto no parece muy dificil con funciones de cadena..

Comment: Si he intentado pero no como hacerlo.. Porque tiene que venir de un array

Comment: Podrias mostrar lo que intentaste??? es importante que la pregunta demuestre lo que intentaste y no funciono, para no darte una solución similar que puede no funcionar...

Comment: Borre lo que estaba haciendo.. Me podrias ayudar como lo podria hacer?

Comment: usa el boton [edit], y agrega a la pregunta lo que intentaste.. mira [ask]. Que demuestres que intentaste algo o que investigaste es parte esencial de la pregunta.

Comment: Como te dije amigo no me funciono de nada sirve colocarla.. :(

Comment: Si, sirve, porque demuestra que intentaste algo, cosa que pedimos siempre, si no, parece que estamos haciendo el trabajo por vos. Y la idea es solucionar problemas.. no hacer el trabajo por vos...

Comment: $resultado = substr("Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Peru.Llamadas", 2);
echo $resultado;

Comment: Estaba probando con la funcion substr

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta añadiendo el resultado que he obtenido

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La forma correcta y escalable es utilizar una expresión regular para extraer el nombre completo del país entre las cadenas inicio [" a "] y fin [".Llamada"]. Funciona para todos los ejemplos.

```
<?php

$nombre = "Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Reuno Unido.Llamada";

preg_match('/ a (.*?).Llamada/is', $nombre, $coincidencias);

print_r($coincidencias[1]); // Reino Unido

?>
```

Documentación oficial de [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) en PHP.Net

Answer (score 8):

Yo te recomiento utilizr `strrpos()` de php ya que este te devolverá la posición por la que necesitas dividir el string y después utilizar `substr()` para partir la frase.

He aquí un ejemplo:

```html
<?php
$array = ["Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Peru.Llamadas","Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Reino Unido.Llamada", "Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Espana.Llamada"];
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
  //echo $array[$i]."\n ";
  $inicio = strrpos($array[$i], " a ") +3;
  $fin = strrpos($array[$i], ".");
  $fin = $fin - strlen($array[$i]);
  $pais = substr($array[$i], $inicio,  $fin);
  echo $pais . " \n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo que haría sería hacer un `explode` por espacios de la cadena de texto, donde dividiría la cadena y se guardaría en un `array`.

```
$cadena = "Roaming atv te da la bienvenida a Peru.Llamadas";
$cadenaExplode = explode(" ", $cadena);
```

El último elemento sería `Peru.Llamadas`. Para recogerlo del `array` basta con obtener el último elemento:

```
$ultimoElemento = end($cadenaExplode);
```

Y volver a hacer un `explode` por punto:

```
$explodePais = explode(".", $ultimoElemento);
$pais = $explodePais[0]; // Este sería el país sólo
```

Comment: en el caso de Reino Unido, esta solucion no funcionaria, ya que te devolveria "Unido.Llamadas" y el ultimo explode devolveria "Unido" en lugar de "Reino Unido"

Comment: Cierto, bien visto. No me había dado cuenta